# Linq to entities group join on multiple tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to perform a group join on multiple tables with one to many relations, using `into` instead of `group by`. But something is not right. I get duplicate records for each Role a user has.

```
from compUsr in Repository.All<CompanyUser>()
join usr in Repository.All<User>() on compUsr.UserId equals usr.Id
join usrRole in Repository.All<UserRole>() on usr.Id equals usrRole.UserId
join role in Repository.All<Role>() on usrRoles.RoleId equals role.Id into roles
    select new UserDTO()
    {
        Id = usr.Id,
        Email = usr.Email
        Roles = roles.Select(r => new RoleDTO()
        {
            Id = r.Id
        })
    }
```

If I remove the join on Role table, and place the `into` statement on UserRole, the grouping works like a charm, but UserRole is just a linking table, so the Role table is the one I'm interested in. Any ideas how to group this as simple as possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from compUsr in Repository.All<CompanyUser>()
join usr in Repository.All<User>() on compUsr.UserId equals usr.Id
join usrRole in Repository.All<UserRole>() on usr.Id equals usrRole.UserId
join role in Repository.All<Role>() on usrRoles.RoleId equals role.Id
group new { usr, role } by usr into grp
                    select new
                    {
                        Id = grp.Key.Id,
                        Email = grp.Key.Email,
                        Roles = grp.Select(r => new RoleDTO()
                        {
                            Id = r.role.Id
                        })
                    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Navigation properties are there for a reason. They make code much more terse and declarative.

With navigation properties this would be easy:

```
from usr in context.Users // or Repository.All<User>()
select new UserDto
{
    Id = usr.Id,
    Email = usr.Email,
    Roles = usr.UserRoles.Select(ur => ur.Roles)
               .Select(r => new RoleDTO()
                            {
                                Id = r.Id
                            }
}
```

I don't know why you also join in `CompanyUser` (you don't seem to use it), but if you need it, you should start the query there and use navigation properties to get to the other entities.

Also, I assume you have more `Role` properties in `RoleDto`. If not, you don't need to select `Role` entities, because `UserRoles` already contains the `Role`'s `Id`.

So it's up to you. You can hang on to the creed that a repository call shall be scoped to exactly one entity (a very narrow definition of "single responsibility"), or use navigation properties for what they were invented for, and consider an aggregate root responsible for the children it encapsulates.

Answer (score -1):

```
from compUsr in Repository.All<CompanyUser>()
join usr in Repository.All<User>() on compUsr.UserId equals usr.Id into eGroup
from u in eGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
join usrRole in Repository.All<UserRole>() on u.Id equals usrRole.UserId into eGroup1
from ur in eGroup1.DefaultIfEmpty()
join role in Repository.All<Role>() on ur.RoleId equals role.Id into eGroup2
from r in eGroup2.DefaultIfEmpty()
group new { u, r } by u into grp
select new
{
      Id = grp.Key.Id,
      Email = grp.Key.Email,
      Roles = grp.FirstOrDefault().r.Id
};
```

Comment: Some explanation of what needed to change to make the code work would be helpful to the original poster and future users.

Comment: With the FirstOrDefault() method you can get access to any relationated field ,and group by any field you want ( usr, role) in a simple way, without repeat the data(complete code snippet).